# Angular ui-grid Display HTML unicode character

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to display HTML unicode characters (check mark or X) in ui-grid cell where values are true or false, respectively.  I was able to do this in a table using ng-switch like below:

```
                        <div ng-switch="company.bitReleased">
                            <div ng-switch-when="true">
                                <span style="color:green; font-size:x-large" ng-bind-html="company.bitReleased | applyMarks | trustedhtml"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div ng-switch-when="false"><span style="color:red; font-size:x-large" ng-bind-html="company.bitReleased | applyMarks | trustedhtml"></span></div>
                        </div>
```

using the following filters:

```
app.filter("applyMarks", function () {
    return function (input) {
        if (input == true) {
            return '&#10004';

        }
        else {
            return '&#10008'
        }
    };

});
app.filter('trustedhtml', function ($sce) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml;
})
```

I found a couple of examples to render HTML in a grid cell, but I can't get any of them to work for my solution.

I tried using the following, but it is not working:

```
cellTemplate: '<div> ng-bind-html="row.entity[col.field] | applyMarks | trustedHtml"</div>'
```

Does anyone know if this is even possible to do?  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ng-bind-html is a directive, and directives need to be bound to an element, does the below not work?

```
'<div><span ng-bind-html="row.entity[col.field] | applyMarks | trustedHtml"></span></div>'
```

Comment: YES!.  It does not work!  Seems I just needed to add the span tags in the div.  Thank you!